# <ESC> equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, ivr

I have been working on an API provided by Zeacom for making IVR calls from our system. 
We are using this API in our C# code. Most of the features are working as expected.

There are few control sequences I am not able to get it to work. As per the documentation, 
All the control sequences follow this general syntax notation:

- `<ESC> \ <parameter> = <value> \`
- `<ESC>` normally represents the escape character `\x1B` (decimal 27) that generates the
  ASCII character 27 (Hex 1B).

The use of the escape character `\x1B` can be supplemented with a user-defined control
sequence using the escape_sequence parameter in the Vocalizer configuration file. This
is particularly helpful for using native control sequences within SSML or other XML
documents because the escape character `\x1B` is not permitted within XML documents
For example `His name is <ESC>\pause=300\ Michael`

Following are the things I tried:

1. Used `<ESC>`. The system instead of treating it as escape it read it as Less than escape and greater than or something like that.
2. I added `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace and

   ```vb
   tts_obj.sText = Strings.Chr(27) + "\\vol=80 \\ " + "I am at 80 Volume ";
   tts_obj.sText += Strings.Chr(27) + "\\vol=90 \\ " + "I am at 90 Volume ";
   tts_obj.sText += Strings.Chr(27) + "\\vol=100 \\ " + "I am at 100 Volume ";
   ```

   This wasn't of any help too.

Any idea how to get this escape character to work in C#?
Any kind of help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does the API give you any error indication? If I'm reading your description of the API correctly, you should be able to do `text = "\x1B\\vol=80 \\ " + "I am at 80 volume ";`

Comment: OP, can you please check the edits? I have a feeling like one of your mentions of `<ESC>` has been double-escaped now.

Comment: Jim,When I do exactly like what you said, it reads as back slash vol=80 back slash I am 80 volume.

Comment: @GSerg: The original question ([revision 1](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27079022/1)) said `<ESC>` (and that wasn't escaped or marked as code, so nothing was shown) in various places. Then, Sam Greenhalgh created [revision 2](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27079022/2), escaping *one* of the several occurrences of `<ESC>` to `&lt;ESC&gt;` (so it was shown as <ESC>). Then I edited something else, then, in [revision 4](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27079022/4), you escaped *all* occurrences of `<ESC>` once again, including the one that had already been escaped.

Comment: `\27` doesn't render as anything in many forms of display. What method are you using to determine that it *reads as back slash vol=80 back slash I am 80 volume*?

Comment: We're trying to help you out, but you're not giving us enough information. I don't know what "it reads as back" is supposed to mean. Do you send that string to the device? Remember, we know *nothing* about this API, so you have to help us out a bit. You say there are a few control sequences you can't get to work. Do *any* of the control sequences that start with `<ESC>` work? If not, how are the working control sequences defined.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding Jim. The API is provided by RealSpeak 4.0 which is now bought by Nuance. The above issue is with the Text to Speech API provided by RealSpeak for our IVR System. No control sequence with <ESC> is working. But most of the SSML tags except Prosody are working.

Comment: I am <say-as interpret-as=address> from SSML. All are working except Prosody which is not supported by RealSpeak